# What is $C$ in the four parameter logistic Law?

Tags: logistic, terminology

It is well known that the four parameter logistic law has the following form 
$$ F(x)=D+\frac{A-D}{1+\Big(\frac{x}{C}\Big)^B} $$

What characterise this curve is its four parameters.

A=starting point of the curve.

B= steepness of the curve.

C=inflection point.

D= Maximum asysmptote.

If I am stating the  definition of the parameters  correctly, I am having a doubt about the parameter  $C$. Indeed, if at  $C$ this curve has an inflection point, then by definition of inflection point we must have  $F''(C)=0$ if  $F''$ exists. 
However, we have 
$$ F''(x)= −\frac{B(D−A)(\frac{x}{C})^B\Big((B+1)(\frac{x}{C})^B−B+1\Big)}{x^2\Big((\frac{x}{C})^B+1\Big)^3} $$
 Thus  $F''(C)= −\frac{B(D−A)}{4C^2} \neq  0$

So, what is $C$ ?  Can  $C $ be an inflection point Without $F''(C)$ being  zero ?

Comment: Hint: If $x$ were time in minutes and you wished instead to express the law in hours, then evidently $x$ would be replaced by $x/60$.  Can you identify $C$ in this expression?

Comment: @whuber Okay, If I suppose that $C$ in the expression is  $60$, then how can I relate this  parameter $C$ to the shape of the curve ? In other words, $C$ in logistic curve refers to what ?  (as I see in your example it is a way of rescaling  x ? ).

Comment: It doesn't change the shape at all: it merely relabels the values of $x$ on its axis.

Comment: @whuber hence, what can we consider   $C$  in a logistic curve ?

Comment: $C$ is a *scale parameter.*

Answer (score 1):

My favorite parameterization of the four-parameters logistic curve is
$$
\boxed{y = A + \frac{D-A}{1+\exp\bigl(B(C-x)\bigr)}}.
$$
Firstly, we straightforwardly see that $y = \frac{A+D}{2}$ for $x = C$. Thus $C$ is the value of $x$ for which $y$ is equidistant from the horizontal asymptotes. This value $\frac{A+D}{2}$ is often of interest in some practical applications (called the $\text{EC}_{50}$ in some contexts in pharmacology).

Secondly, the second derivative is 
$$
\frac{B^2 (A - D) e^{B (C - x)} (e^{B (C - x)} - 1)}{{(e^{B (C - x)} + 1)}^3}.
$$
It equals $0$ for $x = C$. So $C$ is the abscissa of the inflection point.

Comment: This function is not the function in the question: are you using "$x$" to represent the *logarithm* of the $x$ in the question?

Comment: The function in the question is not *a* four-parameters logistic function. There are several parameterizations of these functions, and sometimes they are expressed in the log-scale, yes. There are numerous wrong claims about these functions (e.g. $B$ is the slope at $C$). "My" logistic function is one for which $C$ indeed corresponds to the inflection point. @whuber